# Ask for different ways to solve $(x+y)dy+(y+1)dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x+y)dy+(y+1)dx=0$

Rewrite the equation to 
$\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{x}{y+1}=\frac{-y}{y+1}$

I can use used the integrating factor $μ(y)=e^{-\int\frac{1}{y+1}dy}$ to solve it.

The answer is $x=\frac{-y^2}{2(y+1)}+\frac{C}{y+1}$

I'm curious that are there any other methods to solve this ODE. I am asking for a different method because sometimes I am not able(or haven't enough time, this one costs me about half an hour to solve it ) to  rewrite the equation into a proper form. So, if I could obtain other methods to solve this kind of ODEs, I may have more chances to solve it in a exam.

Comment: it should be $y(x)=x\pm \sqrt{x2+2x+C}$$

Answer (score 6):

See that we can write as
$$(x+y)dy+(y+1)dx=0$$
$$xdy+ydx+ydy+dx=0$$
$$d(xy)+ydy+dx=0$$ now just integrate.

Comment: Nice catch:)  +1

Comment: Plain and straightforward as long as one can see it. +1

Answer (score 3):

Notice, the given D.E. can be easily solved by exact differential form as follows   $$(y+1)dx+(x+y)dy=0$$ Now, comparing the above equation with $Mdx+Ndy=0$, we get $$M=y+1\implies \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=1$$
$$N=x+y\implies \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=1$$
since, $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, hence the given equation is in the exact differential form, hence the solution is given as $$\int_{\text{keeping y constant}} (y+1)dx+\int_{\text{terms free of}\ x}(x+y)dy=C$$
$$ (y+1)\int dx+\int y\ dy=C$$
$$\color{blue}{(y+1)x+\frac{y^2}{2}=C}$$

Comment: What if the case $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\ne \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, then we can't use this method anymore? For example,$2ydy-2ydx+xdy=0$

Comment: Use Integration factor as follows $$\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N}=f(x)$$ or $$\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}=f(y)$$

Comment: I use the first factor but it gives me $(-2-\frac{x}{y})dx+2dy=0$. Am I did it wrong? And does $$\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N}=f(x)$$ and $$\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}=f(y)$$ a general factor that I can always use when$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\ne \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

Comment: Well explained. +1.